# Center align text in select drop down for all browsers

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

How do I Center align text in select drop down for all browsers? Its center aligned in Firefox, but it comes to left in Chrome and Safari.

CSS:

```
.challenge{
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 98%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.challenge select {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: url(images/select_arrow.png) no-repeat right top #ffffff;
  font-family: 'RexBold';
  text-align: center!important;
  text-align: -moz-center;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: #545454;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
}
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML and CSS?

Comment: as far as I know this isn't possible in webkit.

Comment: As per my knowledge, we can do but it will not support for all browsers.

Comment: @user3662273  How to do that?

Comment: :'( over 4 years later and there's still no way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Try with below code. Hope it will work**

```
text-align-last: center; text-align: center;

-ms-text-align-last: center;
-moz-text-align-last: center; text-align-last: center;
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: In html part  

<select>
       <option class="center">Select</option>
       <option class="center">option1</option>
       <option class="center">option2</option>
       <option class="center">option3</option>
       <option class="center">option4</option>
       <option class="center">option5</option>
</select>


Below are the css for this

select .center {
            width: 400px;
            height: 50px;
            -ms-text-align-last: center;
            -moz-text-align-last: center;
            text-align-last: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

Comment: it is using to align center select options

Answer (score 0):

```
.challenge select {
    width:100%;
    background: url(images/select_arrow.png) no-repeat right top #ffffff;
    font-family: 'RexBold';
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#545454;  
    border: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Replace with this code

Comment: Did not help. In Safari and chrome its still left.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
.challenge select {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can place it in `div`, then set `text-align` to center. That worked for me. [Newbie here]

Answer (score -7):

this worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<Select style="width:500px;padding-left:20%;">
<option>center</option>
</Select>
</body>
</html>
```

**just add padding to select, it wont work for option**
**please vote up if this helped, its free**

Comment: adding fixed padding to the left isn't centering anything.

Comment: it helps, doesn't it ?

Comment: @sevenseacat btw, there are no other ways to do this with css, won't work

Comment: No, The options are of different length. Did not work.

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan adjust them

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the meaning of 'centering'.

Comment: i do, but there are no other ways to do this

Comment: Man!! Then there is no solution or what?

Comment: @sevenseacat align the text(option text) to center(horizontally) of the drop down. text-align: center;